# Python Package not pushed to DevOps Artifacts through Feed

Tags: python, azure-devops, package, azure-artifacts, twine

I have been following a tutorial for publishing a Python package, which is only meant to be used by the members of my organisation, to Azure DevOps Artifacts ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1FC6XVcsew&t=527s)).

I use an azure pipeline:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.7'
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.7'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    python -m pip install --upgrade build setuptools twine
    python -m build
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pytest
  displayName: 'pytest'

# Publish code to a previously created feed
- task: TwineAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    artifactFeed: feed-name
- script: |
   python -m twine upload -r feed-name --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*.whl
```

but the `CmdLine` step of the pipeline fails with the following error message:

```
Received "500: Internal Server Error - Failed to retrieve data from the upstream package source 'https://pypi.org/': Forbidden (Forbidden) (DevOps Activity ID: some-id-string)"
```

I have also tried using Microsoft's suggested way of building the package locally and pushing it to Artifacts using `feed-name`, but it fails with the exact same message.

Questions:

1. Has this ever happened to you, and how did you fix it?
2. Why is it using https://pypi.org/ as an upstream package source when I have the code locally, so nothing exists on pypi regarding this package?
3. Why is it even mentioning https://pypi.org/ when I want my package to be restricted to the members of my organisation only? Maybe I don't have to use `twine`?

Comment: I just ran into this issue myself, but had no such problem on 9/27 (deployed successfully many times before with same setup). Is it possible something changed in Azure Artifacts or PyPi?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem after being able to release just two days ago with the same `setup.py`, Artifact Feed, etc.

It looks like the issue might have to do with a connection problem between Azure DevOps Artifacts and PyPi? I went into `Feed Settings` > `Upstream Sources` and saw this:

[image: Upstream Sources Screen]

Clicking the error link showed me this modal popup:

[image: Error Message]

which isn't too helpful, and is also strange since it seems like pypi.org is up and running just fine (checked here: https://status.python.org/).

I don't see any option to refresh upstream sources and when I tried adding a new source, it didn't give me an option to add a new Python source (just `npm`).

So I guess I will just have to hope that this truly is a transient issue that will resolve itself over the weekend.

### Update 10/1/2022

I retried my `twine upload` call today and I was able to release without any issues -- the issue appears to have been transient.